# SharePoint Designer Error Errors were found when compiling the workflow

Tags: workflow, error

I was looking for a solution to allow a group of employees to approve a task on a single workflow for redundancy in SharePoint 2010. i.e if a employee was away the other could approve it for him.

I found a way of enabling it however this has caused an error when I try to publish the workflow.

It keeps coming up with the error after trying to validate the workflow;

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.

In advance it says;

> Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances

I am working on a site where our SharePoint server is kept off site an I have no access to change any configuration.

All I need to understand if it is SharePoint Designer level or Server level?
If it is server level I can pass to the SharePoint Engineers.

Comment: Can you specify what you changed in order to, as you say, *enable it* - that caused the compilation error?

Comment: When in SharePoint designer, I opened the workflow and the line where I start the approval process, I right click and change the properties.

Comment: When in properties I changed the TaskProcessOwner to the group that I have allowed to approve this workflow.